# ASP Response.Redirect Does Not URLEncode "+" Sign

Tags: asp-classic, urlencode, response.redirect

Before IIS 5.0 Response.Redirect was not encoding the string you privide. It was your own responsibility to URLEncode the string.

On IIS 4.0 we used

```
Response.Redirect Server.URLEncode("Page,One.asp")
```

With IIS 5.0 we started just using

```
Response.Redirect("Page,One.asp")
```

So the new Response.Redirect function URLEncodes your string and there is no other option.

There is just one problem. I can not pass a "+" sign in the strings.
When `Response.Redirect("sum=1+3")` is executed, you expect it to encode all the non alphanumeric characters but "+" sign turns into a space character on the receiving page.

When `Response.Redirect(“sum=1%2B3”)` is executed, "404 Not Found" is received because "sum%3D1%25B23" does not exist on the server as %2B is encoded twice.

I want "+" to be encoded as %2B so that the receiving page understands that it is in fact a part of some text and display it.

Let me give you an example:
When you type
**http://translate.google.com/#en|tr|1%2B2**
into your browser and pres enter you will see that google accepts %2B and decodes it as a + in the textarea.

Neither

> Response.Redirect("http://translate.google.com/#en|tr|1%2B2")

or

> Response.Redirect("http://translate.google.com/#en|tr|1+2")

does the same effect as in the example i gave. I just want to redirect to that page.

There is an other way like first encoding the string and then redirecting with `Response.Redirect unescape("Page%2COne%2Easp")` but escape and unescape functions support some part of UTF-8 and ASCII (0-127) but do not support high ANSI (128-255) characters, notably European accented characters.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

*So the new Response.Redirect function URLEncodes your string and there is no other option.*

what do you mean there is no other option ?

server.urlencode still exists

Comment: thanks. i have found a way to to it. you are right! server.urlencode still works but when you want to to a redirection with response.redirect, it is encoded or not it encodes it again. so now i use response.addheader("Location",server.url encode("string"))

Comment: I've use a javascript redirection like here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery