# UrlEncoding and Response.Redirect with %20 and +

Tags: asp.net, urlencode, response.redirect

I am trying to perform the following task in asp.net

```
Response.Redirect("/?confim&name=John%20Smith");
```

When this code is executed the url I see in the browser address is 
"www.mysite.com/?confirm&name=John+Smith".

But what I want is "www.mysite.com/?confirm&name=John%20Smith".

I know that %20 and + are in place of a space and I know it would probably be better to have the name something like "John_Smith".  But I am integrating with a third party piece of software etc, with old data and for legacy reasons it cant change.

I have tried this in another vanilla site and I don't receive the problem, so I cant help but wonder if its a global setting or something that I am missing or haven't heard of.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Will

Comment: What do you see in the page source - a `%20` or a `+`?

Comment: Page source? sorry you've lost me there, its the browser address, are you saying whats the raw url once the redirect hits the server?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I understand what about the encoding you don't like---

The + is a reserved character. So even if you replace spaces with +, the + will be replaced with a % code. And " " should be replaced with %20 anyhow, and if it isn't you can use the HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode method.  And if that doesn't already work, then try this hack:

```
string someUrlEncodedMyWay = "www.mysite.com/?confirm&name=John%20Smith";
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");

Response.Write("window.location = \"" + someUrlEncodedMyWay + "\"");

Response.Write("</script>");
```

And that will allow you to tell the browser to use a funky URL, but if the browser doesn't want to, you might end up with a different encoding of the spaces and special characters.

Comment: I have no personal issue with it, but the third party product that looks at urls needs to use %20 instead of +

Comment: Another possible solution: response.addheader("Location",server.url encode("string"))  which I got from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765453/asp-response-redirect-does-not-urlencode-sign